# How use Repo tool in the local AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I'm working on AOSP, which I got from an OEM (without any CVS like Git or Repo). So I tried to get all Android projects using repo init ...

I followed all the docs but most of them talks about the AOSP mirror, How to track the Android project with repo?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry,Your question was not clear.

Comment: I'm going to echo @Mad Code here and say your question is not clear. If you are getting the code from an OEM and repo isn't included I would guess they have their own method of version control.

Answer (score 1):

If you have received all the source code without and VCS (Git or Repo) like say as a tarball then you cannot use the repo, and if you create manifest by yourself also it is too much work for almost no result.

Instead, create a new Git/Gerrit repository and use the same. All review and CI/CD can be done via the same.